# excel if cell includes XYZ copy to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a downloaded bank statement on SHEET1 (ALL).
I have several widgets running along the side one of which

```
=SUMIF(C:C,H3,D:D)
```

Searches the Descriptions for the value in H3 (EG: * WAGES *) and totals up the corresponding value in D.

I now need to expand that so that it copies the entire ROW onto a new Spreadsheet.

I'd also like, if possible, to start with an input box so I can search for multiple things at once.

Various code that I have seen / tried will only work for exact values in Row C.  But with the bank statement its never the same twice and I'd like it to wildcard the search if possible.

Thanks for your time.

Kind Regards

Alex Nicol

Comment: record a macro and post the code you get

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written VBA code just like this.  Where I use the word payments, you can use the word Wages and include your wildcards like so:

```
a.Cells(b.Row, 16).Value LIKE "*Wages*"


Sub ShortTerm()
Dim a As Range, b As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim p As Long
Dim value1 As Variant

 i = 4 'the start row for pasting

Set a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payments").UsedRange

For Each b In a.Rows

'in the next line change 16 to reflect the column where WAGES is found
If a.Cells(b.Row, 16).Value = "Short Term" Then
For j = 1 to 16
value1 = a.Cells(b.Row, j).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DestinationSheet").Cells(i, j).Value = value1
Next

i = i + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Obviously I am only copying 16 columns and so if that is all you want, this should work. If you need more, make that loop larger. There is probably a way to copy the whole row, but I had originally only wanted specific cells and I had wanted them reorganized which is why I did it the way I did.

See the post on my blog here:

http://automatic-office.com/?p=355